# Как в Python импортировать функцию, чтобы она использовала импорты из главного файла?

Tags: python, python-import

Имеется 2 Python-файла: `Main.py` и `Second.py`

Первый содержит импорт библиотеки `cowsay`, а также импортирует функцию из второго файла. Второй файл не содержит импортов, а имеет только функцию `func()`, которая использует библиотеку `cowsay`.

Поскольку во втором файле функция `func()` нигде не вызывается, считаю ненужным импортировать библиотеку, так как она импортируется в главном файле, перед вызовом `func()` из второго файла.

Но, разумеется это не работает, так как они независимы друг от друга. Все же есть ли способ сделать так, чтобы функция из второго файла работала используя `from cowsay import cow` из первого?

`Main.py`:

```
from cowsay import cow
from Second import func

func('Test')
```

`Second.py`

```
def func(text):
    cow(text)
```

---

Ожидаемый результат:

```
  ____
< Test >
  ====
         \
          \
            ^__^
            (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Comment: Нужно либо импортировать, либо передавать `cow` как параметр в `func`.

Comment: `считаю ненужным импортировать библиотеку` язык python с вами не согласен.

Comment: Пропишите `from cowsay import cow` в теле функции `func`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно явно передать в функцию другую функцию (этакое внедрение зависимости):

Main.py:

```
from cowsay import cow
from Second import func

func(cow, 'Test')
func(lambda text: print(len(text)), 'Test')  # Передаем любую другую произвольную функцию
```

Second.py

```
def func(func_to_call, text):
    func_to_call(text)
```